# I am looking for a code that selects the specified range in a row where column A has value of x

Tags: excel, vba

[image: screenshot]
Ideally, what i need is to email the sepcified range rows with "x" in their column, i tried a code and it's working grand but the only problem is that it's sending 3 emails for 3 rows, but i want to send all the records in one email. I was able to do that using a vba code that converts the selected range in HTML and email it out. Now i want to automate the selection part.So basically i need to select the specified range of any row which have "x" in first column.

I tried a code but it's only selecting the last row that contains "x".
Link for the image showing what i am exactly looking for - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1RUV.jpg

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim toDate As Date
Dim Sheets As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
  If (Cells(i, 1)) = "x" Then  'change this range

      Set r1 = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))
      r1.Select

    On Error Resume Next

    On Error GoTo 0
    Cells(i, 10) = "Selected " & Date + Time 'column J
End If
Next i
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Autofilter or Find would be better than looping (2) Remove the On Error lines as they mask errors and do not appear to do anything anyway (3) If you are selecting only the last selection will show as you are looping through. What should happen that isn't? Selecting things anyway is usually unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: I suppose the bottom line is what is the point of the selecting? The only real thing your code does is put something in column J. Why not use a formula?

Comment: Use some of the functions available to you, such as `application.worksheetfunction.match("x"`    also, may be worth thinking of X and x, you are only checking for lower case.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add information to it, rather than in comments. This goes for the picture link as well as the additional explanation. If you want to answer someone who has commented type a `@` followed by their name. This will put a message in the person's Inbox so that they see you've replied.

Comment: @SJR Please see the updated post and guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsheeran posted the bulk of this, but deleted his answer because it wasn't finished.

As previously stated, there is probably no reason to select anything.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim toDate As Date
Dim Sheets As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "x" Then
        Set r1 = Union(IIf(r1 Is Nothing, Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 3), r1), Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 3))
        Cells(i, 10).Value = "Selected " & Date + Time
    End If
Next i

If Not r1 Is Nothing Then r1.Select

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```